# How to find out which Play version I'm using?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

Kinda silly question, but I used [Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) to get started with the play framework, and now need to see what version I'm using. 2.3 came out with support for docker, but when I put

`dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000, 9443)`

in my `build.sbt`, it complains it doesn't know what dockerExposedPorts is, so I'm thinking I might be running 2.2.

Comment: It actually does... `activator docker:stage` works as of 2.3

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Type `playVersion` within the activator console.

Alternatively you can look in `project/plugins.sbt` for the line

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.2")
```

In this example, the play version is 2.3.2

Comment: Hi James, does playVersion just show the plugin.sbt or gets version from binaries? could exists a mismatch there? Thanks, Luis

Comment: I got "[error] Not a valid command: playVersion" when typing playVersion into the activator console. However, I did see the Play version inside the project/plugins.sbt file.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to list and highlight all play versions in a play project. Works for a multi-module project as well.

The following was tested on macOS Sierra using the default BSD `find` that it comes with and GNU grep installed via `brew install grep`. The latter is required since the following command requires a grep that supports Perl regex (which BSD grep does not).

You can check if the grep on your PATH has Perl-regex support by doing this (should show that the `-P` option is available):

```
    $ ggrep --help | grep -i Perl
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

(ggrep is the GNU grep installed via Homebrew)

And now, on to the actual command (note the **g**grep in the command):

```
   $ find . -name "plugins.sbt" -exec ggrep -PHin --color=always 'com.typesafe.play.*sbt-plugin.*%\s*"\K.*?(?=")' {} \;
```

which outputs:
[image]

Quick notes about the grep options (extracted from grep help):

```
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
  -H, --with-filename       print file name with output lines
```